# Avoid duplicate values by comparing two datatable

Tags: c#, datatable, duplicate-data

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Comparing two datatable and getting the duplicate values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13626900/comparing-two-datatable-and-getting-the-duplicate-values)

I have two DataTable t1 and t2.

```
t1 has 2 fields (SPARTE_ID, SPARTE both as string)

t2 has 2 fields (sparte_id, sparte both as string)

all rows (value) of SPARTE(of t1) is null

I have to bring values from t2 (if sparte_id == SPARTE_ID) and update t1.
```

I can do all these easily.

But the problem is, I have to find out whether t2 have more than 1 same sparte_id with different sparte value. If I get anything like this, I must not UPDATE t1's SPARTE field across this SPARTE_ID AND Have to make a list of these sparte_id's and there sparte.

I will be glad if anyone can tell How would I get the values with this condition? I'm using VS-2010 on .NetFramework 3.5.

**None of them are Primary key or Unique key.

**If you don't understand anything please ask me .

Comment: Please edit your earlier question. Do not repost the same question.

Comment: can i delete any of my questions?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to find your ambigous ID-Sparte combinations:

```
var t2IdDups = t2.AsEnumerable()
    .GroupBy(r => r.Field<string>("SPARTE_ID"))
    .Where(g => g.Count() > 1);
var t2Ambiguous = t2IdDups
    .Where(g =>
        g.Any(r =>
            r.Field<string>("SPARTE") != g.First().Field<string>("SPARTE")))
    .Select(g => new
    {
        SparteID = g.Key,
        Spartes = string.Join(",", g.Select(r => r.Field<string>("SPARTE")))
    });
foreach (var x in t2Ambiguous)
    Console.WriteLine("ambiguous ID={0} Spartes={1}"
        , x.SparteID, x.Spartes);
```